# Pandas - Get unique values from column along with lists of row indices where they appear

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe has a string column that can contain long strings. I want to get a list of unique strings, and also a list for each unique string containing row indices where it appears.

I can think of two ways of doing this.

1. First get the unique list using `.unique()` and then iterate over the dataframe to build up lists of indices where each unique value shows up
2. Use `.groupBy()` to create groups and get the lists of row indices in each group

But I am not quite sure which one is more efficient (or if there are other ways to do this more efficiently). The reason I am thinking about efficiency is that the field I want to uniquify and groupBy is a string field possibly having long strings!

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
    col
0  aaaa
1  bbbb
2  aaaa
3  aaaa
4  bbbb
5  cccc

In [17]: df.groupby('col').groups
Out[17]:
{'aaaa': Int64Index([0, 2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 'bbbb': Int64Index([1, 4], dtype='int64'),
 'cccc': Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')}
```

or as a DataFrame:

```
In [31]: pd.DataFrame([[k,v.values]
                        for k,v in df.groupby('col').groups.items()], 
                      columns=['col','indices'])
Out[31]:
    col    indices
0  aaaa  [0, 2, 3]
1  bbbb     [1, 4]
2  cccc        [5]
```

Comment: fabulous! so grouping by a column that can have long string values is not a bad idea, right?

Comment: How would I get only the first index of the unique values in a 'row'-array?So [[0,1,5]]?

Comment: @Jeroen, `df["col"].drop_duplicates().index` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your DataFrame is `df` and your string column is `string`, you could use this:

```
df.drop_duplicates('string')['string'].apply( \
lambda x: df[df['string'] == x].index.tolist())
```

Comment: thank you. this works but groupBy approach is much cleaner unless this approach is more efficient. comment?

Comment: I agree, I think `groupby().groups` is pretty slick :)